# Разделение массива на равные части (при этом каждая часть с другой по сумме примерно совпадает)

Tags: php

Всем привет. За основу взят алгоритм O(n log n) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem
Только проблема в том, что конструкция не жизнеспособна в случае если на вход может приходить разное кол-во колонок

```
<?php

function partList($arr, $groups) {

$a = [];
$b = [];
$c = [];

$arrCount = count($arr);
$result = [];

sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

for ($i = 0; $i < $arrCount; $i++) {
    if (array_sum($a) < array_sum($b)) {
        $a[] = $arr[$i];
    } else if (array_sum($b) < array_sum($c)){
        $b[] = $arr[$i];
    } else {
        $c[] = $arr[$i];
    }
}


var_dump($a, $b, $c);
}


$arr = [1,2,4,7,1,6,2,8];

partList($arr, 3);
```

Т.е. не понимаю что дальше делать с groups, как должен выглядеть встроенный в for еще один цикл который примет кол-во груп и разобьет на них чтобы не приходилось каждый раз расписывать условия?

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a823a059aa787339dd823cc1b3e23b9879b2b99a

Comment: он разобьет массив на равные части, а по алгоритму нужно чтобы цифры группировались по схожим суммам примерно

Comment: Чего? `array_chunk` - возвращает массив, разделенный на равные части, последний массив из полученных может содержать меньшее количество значений, чем указано в `size`. Иначе просто невозможно сделать.

Comment: в вашей ссылке приведен не алгоритм, а сама задача, и несколько вариантов ее решения. в конце статьи сказано. что для N-групп следует изучать [другую задачу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: @And по сумме надо разбить, а не по числу элментов. Чтобы сумма чисел в каждой части была примерно одинакова. минимизироватьразницу этих сумм. задача оптимизации.

Comment: @teran, а, то есть ему нужно  разбирать указанное количество элементов, допустим 3, и каждые 3 суммировать так, чтобы они были похожи с следующим, а последний получается не важно ибо элементов может быть меньше или другая сумма?

Comment: @And примерно так, да, в данном случае только мы всю сумму чисел массива берем за 100% и остатка как такового не будет, (т.е. 4й группы) всего 3 группы которые примерно равны между собой по сумме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
function partList($arr, $groups = 3){
    $newArray = array_fill(0, $groups, []);
    rsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
    foreach ($arr as $value){
        usort($newArray, function($one, $thwo){
            return array_sum($one) > array_sum($thwo);
        });
        $newArray[0][] = $value;     
    }
    return $newArray;
}
$arr = [1,2,4,7,1,6,2,8];
print_r(partList($arr));
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

Ну это конечно еще не совсем точно будет считать, если будут злобные числа...
В теории, если будут числа соответствовать суммам, посчитает правильно, а так, будет наглядные числа...